# Fantasy series about a human girl with gold tattoos who makes too much blood

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

The cover of the book has a white haired girl with a sword. It is set in Florida in the future sometime. She is a special breed of human that produces more blood than normal and is bred to be like a personal vampire bloodbag. The more gold tattoos you have, the better your blood tastes. Her vampire owner is found dead and she is accused of murdering him so she goes on the run to her aunt's place. She has to clear her name before she gets killed. On the way she meets a vampire who is cursed so that he cannot drink from the vein or he will drain a person dry.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please see [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) to help improve your question. First, when did you read this?

Comment: "The .net gold tattoos you have"? I suspect autocorrect's vile hand at work. But how could "more" be replaced by ".net"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha in some contexts, swishing up from certain characters will give " or ', and in other contexts, .com and .net.

Comment: @Harper Ok, but perhaps it should be fixed? It is clearly "more", and if so, should I change it? I don't have sufficient rep to edit, and I'm not sure it would fall under the 6 char limit.

Comment: @FaheemMitha everyone should be able to edit, your lack of I think 10k rep means you'll just have to sit in the stack for approval.  I am in the same boat.

Comment: @Harper Well, I made that edit, but I'll still just guessing that that is what was meant.

Answer (score 18):

That's Kristen Painter's House of Comarré series.  There are 5 novels and a short story.

Copy from the first book, [*Blood Rights*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9571401-blood-rights?from_search=true)

> Born into a life of secrets and service, Chrysabelle's body bears the telltale marks of a comarré—a special race of humans bred to feed vampire nobility. When her patron is murdered, she becomes the prime suspect, which sends her running into the mortal world...and into the arms of Malkolm, an outcast vampire cursed to kill every being from whom he drinks.
>
> Now, Chrysabelle and Malkolm must work together to stop a plot to merge the mortal and supernatural worlds. If they fail, a chaos unlike anything anyone has ever seen will threaten to reign.

You can see her gold tattoos on all the book covers.  She doesn't have a sword on the first book's cover, but does on a couple of them, such as the 2nd book:

[image: Pale, white-haired woman with golden tattoos draws a sword.]

---

Some other items that may be familiar:  Malcolm lives with a werewolf who is cursed and a ghost on a boat in the harbor.  Chrysabelle's aunt is a former Comarre who got out (and is wheel-chair bound from the fight, I believe).
The vampires have clans each with a special power (such as Alchemy) depending on who turned you, but you can be "re-turned" to change clans.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, NyxxieShade, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @NyxxieShade please accept the answer with the checkmark :-)